# ASP.NET TextOutputFormatter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am creating set of output formatters in .net 6, e.g. CsvOutputFormatter. My class looks as follows

'''
public class CsvOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter

```
{
    public CsvOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/csv"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
    }

    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (context.Object is DocDto doc)
        {
            await response.WriteAsync(FormatAsCsv(doc), selectedEncoding);
        }
        else if (context.Object is List<DocDto> docList)
        {
            foreach (var docItem in docList)
            {
                await response.WriteAsync(FormatAsCsv(docItem), selectedEncoding);
            }
        }
    }

    public string FormatAsCsv(DocDto doc)
    {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder();

        buffer.AppendLine($"\"{doc.Id}\";\"{String.Join(",", doc.Tags)}\";\"{String.Join(",", doc.Data.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value))}\"");

        return buffer.ToString().Trim();
    }

}
```

'''

The format on the output is correct, however Swagger shows also error:
**Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text.**

What is the issue?